# hyperlink + pdftooltip: content to show tooltip with mouse hover, and be a clickable hyperlink simultaenously

Tags: hyperref, pdfcomment, tooltips

I would like to have some hyperlinked content also show a tooltip when the mouse is hovered. Simple use case: when referencing say `Section 1`, the tooltip could display the section name `Introduction To This Document`, or with Figures, it could display the caption. I've seen this question asked before in some variation, but have not found a solution. I would prefer to use simple tooltips (to ensure wider compatibility), and therefore want to use the `pdfcomment` package. When testing my document with Sumatra and Adobe, the hyperlinks work, but the tooltip does not appear.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \pdftooltip{Plain text with tooltip}{The tooltip text}
    \pdftooltip{\hyperlink{target}{hyperlinked text within tooltip}}{The tooltip text}
    \hyperlink{target}{\pdftooltip{tooltipped text within hyperlink}{The tooltip text}}
    \newpage
    \hypertarget{target}{hyperlink target text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: well the problem is that you have two annotations of the same size on top of each other. So how should the pdf viewer know which one it should show you if you hover with the mouse?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I imagined that was part of the problem. However, when I move my cursor over "Ulrike Fischer" in the comment you made, a tooltip pops up showing your (impressive) reputation of +260k, I don't think it's unreasonable to expect that pdfs might have those facilities to perform both as well.

Comment: well browser can do more stuff here - all browsers can handle javascript, and show videos and animations. You don't get this with every pdf viewer.  Ask the sumatra or adobe support what to do here ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I also noticed when l hover over a `\url{...}`, the link appears in a tooltip on Sumatra. Perhaps my request is not out of reach...

Comment: the problem is not the tooltip, but the two conflicting annotations. With an url you have only one.